# bootstrap 3 imported but still the 2.3 version style buttons - why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have had bootstrap version 2.3 before and now i imported the 3rd version but the buttons have still the old version. Even if i put this:

```
<!-- Standard gray button with gradient -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
```

it is showing up like this:

[image]

any ideas why?

**EDIT**: this is what i have in the head

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: You have downloaded on http://getbootstrap.com/?

Comment: yeah. i just downloaded the whole package.

Comment: can you show us all <link> tags in your <head> ?

Comment: @NIA, sure. just a second, please see my edit

Comment: no other js/css loaded in other places on your page ?

Comment: @LeGEC, there are. can there be a conflict?

Comment: Don't the official Bootstrap docs use a flat theme that override the default 2.x theme?

Comment: You have import the libraries which are in the folder 'dist'?

Comment: whats it supposed to be instead?

Comment: are you still referencing bootstrap2.3 in your head as well? otherwise, seems like browser cache to me ..

Comment: Ah, I just thought that you might either 1) included a `bootstrap-theme.css` which indeed make it look 2.3-like *OR* 2) forgotten some links to your old bootsrap's files *OR EVEN* 3) misplaced a new css so you are actually including an old one. Sorry if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @LeGEC, now i got it. I had ``bootstrap-select.css`` if i delete it, it is working. so there is conflict with it. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Then probably you need to update your `bootstrap-select.css`, they might support 3.0 in the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you load other javascript/css files in your page ?

If so, it's a "last man stands" situation.

Comment: you are right. there is a conflict, i loaded also bootrsrap-select.css which was the reason.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are using the correct files, then try clearing the cache in your browser.